# Error Rosmake usb_camera

Tags: ros, rosdep, rosmake, rosdistro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Good evening

We are trying to "rosmake" the package usb_camera but rosmake fail. Here is the output :

> mkdir -p bin
>
> cd build && cmake -Wdev
> -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/rostoolchain.cma$
>
> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
>
> -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.6.3
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
>
> -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
>
> -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
>
> -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
>
> -- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
>
> [rosbuild] Building package usb_cam
>
> Failed to invoke
> /opt/ros/groovy/bin/rospack
> deps-manifests usb_cam
>
> [rospack] Error: the rosdep view is
> empty: call 'sudo rosdep init' and
> 'rosdep update'
>
> CMake Error at
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:129
> (message):
>
> Failed to invoke rospack to get
> compile flags for package 'usb_cam'.
> Look above for errors from rospack
> itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
> broken dependency!
>
> Call Stack (most recent call first):
> /opt/ros/groovy/share/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:203
> (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
> CMakeLists.txt:5 (rosbuild_init)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! make: *** [all] Error 1

I´ve tried to do sudo rosdep init and the rosdep update but the update also failed :

pi@raspberrypi ~ $ rosdep update
reading in sources list data from /etc/ros/rosdep/sources.list.d
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/osx-homebrew.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/gentoo.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/base.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/python.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/rosdep/ruby.yaml
Hit https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/raw/master/releases/fuerte.yaml
Query rosdistro index https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/index.yaml

ERROR: Rosdep experienced an error: Unable to handle 'index' format version '2', please update rosdistro
Please go to the rosdep page [1] and file a bug report with the stack trace below.
[1] : http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep

rosdep version: 0.10.20

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 118, in rosdep_main
exit_code = _rosdep_main(args)

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 261, in _rosdep_main
return _no_args_handler(command, parser, options, args)

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 269, in _no_args_handler
return command_handlerscommand

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/main.py", line 426, in command_update
error_handler=update_error_handler)

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/sources_list.py", line 422, in update_sources_list
for d, dist in get_index().distributions.iteritems():

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdep2/rosdistrohelper.py", line 58, in get_index
_RDCache.index = rosdistro.get_index(_RDCache.index_url)

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdistro/**init**.py", line 106, in get_index
return Index(data, base_url)

File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/rosdistro/index.py", line 51, in **init**
assert int(data['version']) == 1, "Unable to handle '%s' format version '%d', please update rosdistro" % (Index._type, int(data['version']))

AssertionError: Unable to handle 'index' format version '2', please update rosdistro

What´s happening? Can you help me please ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128296/error-rosmake-usb_camera/) by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2014-02-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-11**:
I have also followed this " [http://answers.ros.org/question/122266/how-can-i-fix-unable-to-handle-index-format-version-2-please-update-rosdistro/"](http://answers.ros.org/question/122266/how-can-i-fix-unable-to-handle-index-format-version-2-please-update-rosdistro/%22) but everything is up to date ...

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
What are your ROS and OS versions?

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-11**:
Ros groovy and Raspbian wheezy

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-02-11**:
It sounds like the version of python-rosdep that's available in the repository that you're using isn't up to date. I would try to get in contact with the repository maintainer.

**Comment by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) on 2014-02-12**:
Thanks for your help. I´ll try to get in contact witg him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started a thread into https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ros-sig-embedded/6IEx-SqhaAo and repositorys of raspbian groovy have been updated.
I have upgrade by apt-get upgrade and everything was finally fine!

---

Originally posted by [4LV4R0](https://answers.ros.org/users/7366/4lv4r0/) with karma: 70 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0